# What does "[V+ECX*2-2]" refer to in memory exactly?

Tags: x86, nasm, addressing-mode

So i have this exercise to  solve: "Given a vector V of x 16 bit  integers, check if the vector only  contains  even numbers. If it is the case, EAX will equal  1, otherwise  0. x is saved at the address n and has 16  bits. Here is the solution:

```
    MOVZX ECX, WORD [n]
    XOR EAX, EAX
bcle:
    TEST WORD [V+ECX*2-2], 1
    LOOPZ bcle
    JNZ sinon
    INC EAX
sinon:
```

Now i am stuck at [V+ECX*2-2]... maybe I am wrong but I believe the ECX register at this point contains a number which we are checking whether its even or not... and if thats the case why would we look for that address in memory? I have looked up on many websites and books how memory addressing works but I can never apply to exercises, maybe if someone here could explain to me with a simple example i would appreciate it...

Comment: This loop has so many missed optimizations...  `test byte [v+ecx*2-2], 1` would save 2 bytes and avoid an LCP decoding stall on Intel CPUs.  (`test r/m16, imm8` doesn't exist, only the imm16 version.  Instructions with 16-bit immediates in 32-bit mode can stall because the operand-size prefix changes the length of the rest of the instruction.)  Also, `loop` is slow on Intel CPUs; it really would be faster to `test/jnz` as the loop body inside a `dec/jnz` loop.  But this loop fails at optimizing for performance *or* code size.  Also, an indexed addressing mode will unlaminate on Intel.

Comment: Also, if your array is static, normally the size can be an assemble-time constant instead of also being stored in memory.  Like `n  equ  $ - V` right after `V` is defined.  I know none of that is what you were asking, but this imperfectly-optimized loop was bothering me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ECX` here contains an index (more precisely index+1) of current number in `V` array, not a number itself. It's index+1, because `ECX` was initialized with `n` (as in 1-based array, not with `n-1` as in 0-based array) in `MOVZX ECX, WORD [n]`.

`[V+ECX*2-2]` - is calculating an address of the number indexed by `ECX`:

- `V` - is an address of the array,
- `ECX*2` - is a calculating an offset to the `ECX`'th element in the array's memory, `*2` - because we are dealing with 2-bytes numbers (16-bit)
- `-2` - is a changing 1-based-array-index into 0-based-array-index, as offset must be 0-based, again `-2` because we're using 2-bytes numbers
- `[...]` - is taking a value by the address inside brackets
- `WORD` - taking a 2-bytes value

Worth noting that `V+...-2` is allowed because `V` - is a compile time constant, so compiler can calculate `V-2` as another constant and put it into compiled binary. If `V` would be a dynamic value `[V+...-2]` would not fit into a single instruction, and the address need to be calculated separately.

Comment: Actually, if V was replaced by a 32-bit GPR, it could be encoded as eg `word [eax + ecx*2 - 2]` in which case only the constant -2 would be used for the displacement.